# Can I create a shared Google calendar where users can add and edit their own events, but not modify other users events?

Tags: google-calendar

I want to create a Shared Google Calendar that allows users to add events and edit events they have added. A user should not be able to edit an event added by another user.

Is this possible with Google Calendar?

Can such settings be done at the event level by the event creator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible with Google Calendar: sharing settings are rather limited, as you can see below:

[image]

As for the event creator you can only choose there the privacy level you want for the event: default/private/public